# Google sheets query selecting year, month and day from a group of rows containing date and time as string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

```
=QUERY(Activity_2019, "SELECT A,F, YEAR(H), MONTH(H), DAY(H), sum(O) where A='Trades' group by G,A,F, YEAR(H), MONTH(H), DAY(H)",1)
```

I'm trying to sum rows which are grouped by identical cell values. This is working fine until I add also try to print the Day, Month and Year which I'm trying to grab from a string located in column H.

Here are 3 sample rows that produce a correct sum(O) result. Unfortunately, Column H contains a string which holds both date and time. The grouped rows have identical year, month and day and not time as you can see below. Can anyone help me grab the year, month and day only for the summed group? Is this possible with Google Sheets query?

Column H

```
2019-01-03, 09:30:32
2019-01-03, 09:31:17
2019-01-03, 09:35:01
```

Here is a sample google sheet to see what I mean.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-C9bMX687ViakkTf5hXBldeFeu7xRtShTx6RfiYGiS4/edit#gid=0

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Thanks. Added a link to a sheet in the description.

Answer (score 0):

delete all in range **D:F** and paste this in **D1** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Year", "Month", "Day"; 
 IFERROR(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B, {Data!A:A&Data!G:G, 
 TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(Data!H:H, ","),,1), "yyyy♦mm♦dd")}, 2, 0), "♦"))})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you that works well but is there anyway to make it part of the original query?

=QUERY(Activity_2019, "SELECT A,G, sum(O) where A='Trades' group by G,A,F label A 'Type', G 'Stock', sum(O) 'PnL'",1)

Comment: sure, use this in A1: `=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(Activity_2019, 
 "select A,G,sum(O) where A='Trades' group by G,A,F label A'Type',G'Stock',sum(O)'PnL'", 1),
 {"Year", "Month", "Day"; 
 IFERROR(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(Activity_2019, 
 "select A,G,sum(O) where A='Trades' group by G,A,F", 0), 
 "select Col1,Col2 offset 1", 0)),,999^99)), {Data!A:A&" "&Data!G:G, 
 TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(Data!H:H, ","),,1), "yyyy♦mm♦dd")}, 2, 0), "♦"))}})` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne1M0.png

Comment: I tried using it on another sheet and received this error.

Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 391. Actual: 1.

=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(Activity_2019, "select A,G,sum(O) where A='Trades' and G is not null group by G,A label A'Type',G'Stock',sum(O)'PnL'", 1), {"Year", "Month", "Day"; IFERROR(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(Activity_2019, "select A,G,sum(O) where A='Trades' and G is not null group by G,A", 0), "select Col1,Col2 offset 1", 0)),,999^99)), {Data!A:A&" "&Data!G:G, TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(Data!H:H, ","),,1), "yyyy♦mm♦dd")}, 2, 0), "♦"))}})

Comment: can you share a copy of that sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xGKfvMdSfwMH6Nz6YRyBLuuNTyLWVcQSOVVCGxX4gl4/edit#gid=0

Comment: error is caused because you dont have sheet called Data - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCzby.png